# Singular or plural copulative verb in a question?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

Should the copulative verb be singular or plural in this type of sentence:

> A crucial question is / are the causes of misunderstandings ?

Comment: I think it's General Reference that the grammatical *subject* here is "a crucial question" - which is ***singular***, so it requires a singular verb form.

Comment: You’ll also want to have number agreement between “question” and “cause”.

Comment: I would revise to write "A crucial question is one that causes misunderstandings." That sounds better to me, if you are definite _crucial question_ and it avoids the dubious verb form. (I didn't look up a rule, but "is" and "are" both sound a little off in your example, which is why I suggest revising it entirely.) You could also write simply "Crucial questions cause misunderstandings."

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> A crucial question is **what are** the causes of misunderstanding(s)?

*is* matches *question* and *are* matches *causes*.

> **What are** the causes of misunderstanding(s)?

becomes the crucial question.

Also I would consider *misunderstanding* as uncountable, but that may just be me.